# Any alternative of django_braces?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to used SuperuserRequiredMixin fron django braces which is one of the clean way to perform the task but there are multiple dependency issue with this package for Django3.0. I found these two, there might be other as well.

```
  from django.utils.functional import curry, Promise
ImportError: cannot import name 'curry' from 'django.utils.functional' (C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py)
```

```
  File "C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_ajax.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

I know that there are alternative such as package 'Six' and functools.partial for curry but if there are any other package or any other clean way to perform django braces then it will be very helpful thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the django3.0 curry, see https://github.com/django/django/commit/5b1c389603a353625ae1603

Comment: and utils, juet: pip install django-utils-six